# How to change the background color when the server changed the json file

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to create an app that gets the background color of the activity from the server. I need the background color to change when the json file on the server is changed. Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: So what is the issue? There should be some flag in your response and in send request by which you and server both know that color has been changed.

Comment: Please describe clearly, so that we can answer clearly

Comment: Please describe your problem with your written code...

Comment: It should get the color name every second from the server and i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the description is not much clear but what I understood that you want to change activity layout background color based on some json data match from server and local storage. I am assuming that the JSON data is stored somewhere in local file.

You can use a periodic call or [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to sync your json. In any way when you are getting the JSON from server, get the saved JSON from the file. Next, you need to use a string comparision (if need to change the BG color based on JSON change only). Or you can fetch the color code from the server JSON (if getting color code from server as an attribut in the JSON response) and compare it with the color code from the file JSON and change the BG of your activity layout. Let me know if you have any further confusion.